# jenkins does not complete 'execute windows command' step

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I am running a bunch of windows commands as the build step in Jenkins using the "Execute Windows batch command" option. However, the build stops after executing some of the commands, ignoring the rest, and says "Finished: SUCCESS". Here's kind of how my "Execute Windows batch command" looks:

```
xcopy source\dir dest\dir
7z x file_name.zip
cd extracted_dir_name
rmdir /s /q stale_output
command_to_be_run
another_command_to_be_run
post_processing_
copy_and_zip_commands_
```

Jenkins executes until `another_command_to_be_run`, and then just stops as if there are no other commands after that, and says "Finished: SUCCESS".
Why is this happening? How do I execute the post-processing commands?

PS: `command_to_be_run` and `another_command_to_be_run` take more than a few seconds, but I don't know if that matters.

Edit:
I've later tried commenting out `another_command_to_be_run` with `REM`, and then all the other post-processing commands run fine. Soooo Strange! Hope this rings any bells. Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Most likely, one of the commands you are running is a .bat or .cmd file.  Be sure to use the "call" keyword before calling one of those, otherwise your script will stop after that point.

Comment: @BradBales Yes, I think that maybe the problem. One of them is a bat file. Let me try your solution.

Comment: @BradBales Thanks, it worked!! 
Just a small glitch, however:
The commands following the `call batch_file.bat` now run without showing the command on the console. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: You are very welcome!  I have struggled with Jenkins/Hudson under windows before...good luck!

Comment: Most likely the batch file that is being called is setting "echo off".  You might need to do an "@echo on" after that batch file is executed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, one of the commands you are running is a .bat or .cmd file. If you don't use the "call" keyword before calling one of those, your main script will stop after that point.